# Align divs in one line and stick to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS/JS:

```js
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.cart-preview {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-preview a,
.cart-preview a:hover,
.cart-preview a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.cart-preview .header {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.cart-preview .body {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-body {
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .product {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 205px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.taxes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-total {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.taxes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-total .value {
  float: right;
}

.cart-total .label {
  float: left;
}

.taxes .value {
  float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">NAME</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">öffnen</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve, that the div 'product-details' is displayed in the same line as the image and both of them should take `50%` of the place available.
Additionally, i want to stick the checkout div to the bottom of the whole `div`, it is actually not even shown.

As you see, I used `display: inline-block` for the product div, but it is not working, I don't know why.

So bascically i want to achieve: image on the left, details on the right.
There is a lot more `CSS` and `HTML`, for a better readability I removed them.

The whole body is `position: fixed`, because it should always take the full page.

This is a MVCE and should work in a jsfiddle or in codepen.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it looks like some of your selectors weren't even working. Second, you were applying `inline-block` to the parent, when it really should have been applied to the children.

Either way, I think [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) is a better solution here. I also made the image shrink or expand to fill the available space.

```js
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.cart-preview {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-preview a,
.cart-preview a:hover,
.cart-preview a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.cart-preview .header {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.cart-preview .body {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-body {
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
}

.product>div {
  width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.product img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 205px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.taxes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-total {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.taxes {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-total .value {
  float: right;
}

.cart-total .label {
  float: left;
}

.taxes .value {
  float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">NAME</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">öffnen</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, flebox is working well here. Maybe you can try to help me why the checkout div is not displayed

Comment: @ItFreak it's not displaying because of `position: relative;`

Comment: so i should change it to absolute?

Comment: @ItFreak just removing that positioning entirely seems to work ok, though I don't know what you're aiming for. It's up to you.

Comment: I want to have this div at the bottom and set up the margin-bottom

Comment: @ItFreak alright, well that should be a separate question if you really need help with it. Like I said, when I removed position it seemed to act exactly like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.cart-preview a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.cart-preview .header {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.cart-preview .body {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: -400px;
}
.cart-preview .body.open {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shooping-cart-body{
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cart-preview .body .product{
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container > .product-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container > .product-details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before{
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.prodcut-image{
  display:inline-block;
}
.product-details{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.cart-preview .body .checkout {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout > button {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 205px;
  margin-left:100px;
}

.taxes{
  position: absolute;
bottom: 150px;
  left: 0;
}

.cart-total{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.taxes{
    position: absolute;
  bottom: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-total .value{
  float: right;
}
.cart-total .label{
  float: left;
}

.taxes .value{
  float: right;
}
.taxes .label{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="img.svg" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
              </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">NAME</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">öffnen</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
              <div class="cart-total">
        <span class="label">Total</span>
                <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Although html structure should be updated and more refined.